# MySQL enum removing backslashes

Tags: php, mysql, enums, laravel

I'm having an issue setting an enum column type in MySQL. The column value will be a namespaced classname, such as `Accounts\Private`.

The whitelisted values should be `Accounts\Private` and `Accounts\Merchant`.

Enum seems to be removing the `\` from the whitelisted values. Using a double blackslash `\\` doesn't work either.

Oddly, adding three blackslashes `\\\` causes two backslashes to show.

What am I missing? I'm using Laravel and establishing a polymorphic relationship, which requires the classnames to be namespaced.

Comment: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/

Comment: Laravel requires the `account_id` (integer) and `account_type` (string) keys to determine what kind of model the child model belongs to. I was hoping to use `enum` to whitelist `account_type`s. I can just use a standard string otherwise. The mentioned link isn't really appropriate to this use case as we're bound by Laravel conventions.

Comment: @MatthewRuddy did you ever figure out a way to use MySQL's `enum` with Laravel's polymorphic relationships?  I was actually just researching this exact problem and would like to avoid using `varchar` if it is possible.

Comment: @MatthewRuddy Actually, now that I look around, it looks like the best idea may be not to encounter this problem at all by setting a `$morphClass` in the models and, thus, avoiding namespaces with backslashes in the DB at all.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881963/polymorphic-eloquent-relationships-with-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble with MySQL enums.

Laravel 5.3 adds a morphMap feature to allow you to set custom strings (without slashes) to use in place of the namespaced classes. Prior to 5.3 there was a morphClass property that could be set on a model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations