# Laravel - Eloquent: Polymorphic relations with namespace

Tags: namespaces, laravel-4, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

My situation is: a Calendar belongs to a Customer or Salesman

Because I also have classes like Event and File, I used the namespace App\Models for all my model classes.

so I set up the polymorphic relation:

in Calender.php

```
public function user() {
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

in Customer.php and Salesman.php

```
public function calendars() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Calendar', 'user');
}
```

Now when i do

```
$calendar= Calendar::find(1); //calendar from a salesman
$calendar->user; //error here
...
```

I get this error message:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'salesman' not found
```

I noticed that `'salesman'` is low cased, maybe this is the problem?

and this is what I get from Laravels stacktrace

open: /var/www/cloudcube/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

```
// foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
// when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
if (is_null($foreignKey))
{
    $foreignKey = snake_case($relation).'_id';
}

$instance = new $related; //HIGHLIGHTED
```

I had a similar error before on this line, when I was messing with the namespaces, so I guess it has something to do with that. Is there any way I can tell the `morphTo()` method to use the correct namespace?

Or is it something else causing this issue?

Also found this solution, but can't seem to get it working: 
[Polymorphic Eloquent relationships with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881963/polymorphic-eloquent-relationships-with-namespaces)

Comment: you can see what is inserted in database and during query, log your query to see what is sent in query.

Comment: The problem is the query is not excecuted because he can't find 'advisor'. When I manually (by overwriting morphTo()) give the namespace, the query is excecuted but uses 'App\Models\Advisor' to check on type values... SUCKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

I always define relationships with the correct namespace, for example in Calendar:

`public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Event');
    }`

My problem consisted out of 2 complications:

1. `$calendar->user()` with the `morphTo(...)` function was not working because my models were in a namespace, and `morphTo(...)` had no way of giving this namespace.
2. `$salesman->calenders()->get()` returned and empty list, although my relations in the database were there. I found out this is because of bindings with the query.

Solution for 1. : Writing a custom `morphTo(...)` function in Calendar to override the one of Laravel. I used the source of Laravels `morphTo(...)` as a base. The final statement of this function is `return $this->belongsTo($class, $id);` 
There `$class` must be the namespaced class name. I used basic string operations to pull that off.

Solution for 2. : Writing a custom `morphMany(...)` function in Salesman and letting it return a `MyMorphMany(...)` similar to what [Polymorphic Eloquent relationships with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881963/polymorphic-eloquent-relationships-with-namespaces) described.

The problem here is that `$query` that is passed to the `MyMorphMany` constructor has the wrong (namespaced) binding. It will look for `where user_type = "App\\Models\\Salesman"`.

To fix this I used a custom `getResults()` function in `MyMorphMany` which overrides the default Laravels implementation, there I changed the bindings to use the correct, un-namespaced lower cased, class name. Then I called this `getResults()` function in the `get()` function of the `MyMorphMany` class.

I used `$query->getBindings()` and `$query->setBindings()` to correct the bindings.

Hope this saves someone else a few days of work, like it would have saved me :)

Comment: you can also set `protected $morphClass = 'MyMorphMany';` as a class variable, because then you don't need to use a custom `getResults()` function

Comment: I have been trying to solve the same problem for a day and still stuck in it.
Can you please share you modified morphto() and morphmany functions?