# Polymorphic relations in upgraded Laravel app from 4.2 to 5

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5, polymorphic-associations, relationships

**Short:** some related models are returning instances correctly, but some aren't (the polymorphic ones).

I have those three models:

*app/Models/User.php*

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Company');
    }
}
```

*app/Models/Company.php*

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        // Also tested with morphMany, without success
        return $this->morphOne('App\Address', 'addressable');
    }

}
```

*app/Models/Address.php*

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Address extends Model {

    public function addressable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

And the controller:

*app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php*

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// ... many "use" clauses not relevant to the question
use Auth;
// ...

use App\Address;
use App\Company;
use App\User;

class MyController extends Controller {

    // Ok here
    $user = Auth::user();

    // Ok here, too
    $company    = $user->company()->first();

    // Here is the problem; $address is null
    $address    = $company->address()->first();

}
```

The line `$company->address()->first();` is always returning `null` to `$address` in Laravel 5, but it worked well in Laravel 4.2

Comment: Is this on current data from L4 - or new data you are inserting in L5?

Comment: On current data from L4

Comment: In L4 models were not namespaced by default, so they saved `Model` in your table, while now in L5 they save as `Namespace\Model` and are retrieved the same way. So you need to add namespace to your db entries or use `morphClass` property on the models.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, could you add an answer or comment about `morphClass`? I can't find it in documentation

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk, since your solution using `morphClass' worked, you can add an answer and I will select it as the right one.

Comment: Here you go. Also read the linked question and answers - both mine and lukas geiter's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In L4 models were not namespaced by default, so they were saved as `ModelName` in your table, while now in L5 they are rather `Namespace\ModelName` and are retrieved the same way.

That said, your data saved in L4 needs to be adjusted so it matches your current models, or you can use `protected $morphClass` on the models.

However take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27909753/784588) into consideration for the latter solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you open your database - you'll see the relationship in your old L4 data stored as: `User` or `Company`

You need to run a script that updates the columns to the new namespace names - such as `App\User` or `App\Company`

This is because you are now namespacing your models - so Laravel needs to know which namespace to call.

Comment: In `address` table, I have updated each row data in `addressable_type` column, but no success.

Comment: Your solution seems to be right, but I can't get it to work. Then, I tried `morphClass` from @JarekTkaczyk suggestion, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Along with @The Shift Exchange's answer and following my question's example, you can follow [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089231/279712):

Instead of adding the namespace in `addressable_type` column values from `address` table *(and this is a valid solution)*, you can use `$morphClass`:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model {

    protected $morphClass = 'Company';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function address()
    {
        // Also tested with morphMany, without success
        return $this->morphOne('App\Address', 'addressable');
    }
```